# Why can't I use ppprint in my python script

Tags: python-3.x

I'm currently writing a python script and I got this error :

"owner": "python",
"code": "no-name-in-module",
"severity": 8,
"message": "No name 'ppprint' in module 'ppprint'",

Here's my code :

```
    import requests # To make get and post requests to APIs
import json # To deal with json responses to APIs
from ppprint import ppprint # To pretty print json info in a more readable format
```

Comment: did you want to print something etc....???

Comment: pprint  is that a typo.

Comment: It's called ``pprint``, not ``ppprint``.

Comment: @MuhammadRizwanMunawar yes actually I'm trying to run my first API request

Comment: sure, I answered it, Please check it.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Many thanks !! It works better if it's well written :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to properly import `pprint` (included in python standart library):

```
from pprint import pprint
```

or like below code..

```
import requests # To make get and post requests to APIs
import json # To deal with json responses to APIs
from pprint import pprint # To pretty print json info in a more readable format
```

Comment: Thanks mate ! 

I realised that miss written pprint.

Comment: Ok, Sure @DoubleH